# Form elements not identifiable in TestNG

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I am new to selenium. I am trying to write a script to open an application,enter user name and Password and login. I tried doing the same using selenium IDE in firefox. Its working. But when I try the same using selenium and TestNG(JAVA) I am geting the below error :

```
    org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath: /html/body/form[1]/div[2]/table[2]/tbody/tr[4]/td/button (tried for 10 second(s) with 500 MILLISECONDS interval)
    Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: '3169782', time: '2016-09-29 10:24:50 -0700'

    Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
    Capabilities [{browserAttachTimeout=0, ie.enableFullPageScreenshot=true, enablePersistentHover=true, ie.forceCreateProcessApi=false, ie.forceShellWindowsApi=false, pageLoadStrategy=normal, ignoreZoomSetting=false, ie.fileUploadDialogTimeout=3000, version=11, platform=WINDOWS, nativeEvents=true, ie.ensureCleanSession=false, elementScrollBehavior=0, ie.browserCommandLineSwitches=, requireWindowFocus=false, browserName=internet explorer, initialBrowserUrl=http://localhost:9907/, javascriptEnabled=true, ignoreProtectedModeSettings=false, enableElementCacheCleanup=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=dismiss}]
    Session ID: a36f7287-5912-48c0-87b2-3d974262c634
        at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.timeoutException(WebDriverWait.java:80)
        at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:265)
        at com.nagest.nrt.NewTest.userLogin(NewTest.java:47)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

The HTML Snippet of my page is :

```
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>User Id: </td>
                                    <td><input type="text" name="USER" id="USER" onfocus="this.style.border='2px solid #3BB9FF';" onblur="this.style.border='2px solid #737373'" /></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Password: </td>
                                    <td><input type="password" name="PASSWORD" id="PASSWORD" onfocus="this.style.border='2px solid #3BB9FF';" onblur="this.style.border='2px solid #737373'" /></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><input type="hidden" name="TARGET" id="TARGET" value="/epsweb/view/private/search/search.jsf" /></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><button name="Logon" type="submit" onfocus="this.style.border='2px solid #3BB9FF';" onblur="this.style.border='2px solid #737373'">Logon</button></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
```

My TESTNG java code :

```
public void userLogin(){
        driver.get(baseURL + "login url");
        //driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        //driver.findElement(By.id("USER")).sendKeys("aaa");
        waitVar.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"USER\"]"))).sendKeys("aaa");
       waitVar.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"PASSWORD\"]"))).sendKeys("123");;
    //  driver.findElement(By.name("USER")).sendKeys("aaa");
    //  driver.findElement(By.name("PASSWORD")).sendKeys("@123");
        waitVar.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("/html/body/form[1]/div[2]/table[2]/tbody/tr[4]/td/button"))).click();
        String strPageTitle = driver.getTitle();

    }
```

I tried using many combinations but now working. I even tried copying the code from firefox IDE and converted it to java. XPATH is am geting from firebug.

Note : The form elements are visible before 10 seconds.

Update : I tried with the below code

```
 WebElement myelement=driver.findElement(By.id("USER"));
String tag=myelement.getTagName();
        System.out.println("====================="+tag);// ===============input
        myelement.sendKeys("aaaa");
```

The sysout line is geting printed. But, when I use the sendKeys() method, it is throwing the exception.

```
    org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Element is not displayed (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 234 milliseconds
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
Capabilities [{browserAttachTimeout=0, ie.enableFullPageScreenshot=true, enablePersistentHover=true, ie.forceCreateProcessApi=false, ie.forceShellWindowsApi=false, pageLoadStrategy=normal, ignoreZoomSetting=false, ie.fileUploadDialogTimeout=3000, version=11, platform=WINDOWS, nativeEvents=true, ie.ensureCleanSession=false, elementScrollBehavior=0, ie.browserCommandLineSwitches=, requireWindowFocus=false, browserName=internet explorer, initialBrowserUrl=http://localhost:13799/, javascriptEnabled=true, ignoreProtectedModeSettings=false, enableElementCacheCleanup=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=dismiss}]
Session ID: 1c79492b-0fab-497e-9866-cbba060f6c8a
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:636)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:284)
...........
```

**This issue is occuring only in IE11. I tried in chrome it works correctly.**

Comment: For the login button try a direct xpath --- "//button[@name='Logon']"and check if it works... Assuming you only one button with that name or it is the first one in the page

Comment: @Grasshopper:updated the code. Pls look now

Comment: What is the exception you are getting now with the updated code?

Comment: @Grasshopper: If I use driver.findElement, I am not geting any error. But using sendKeys() throws the exception

Answer (score 0):

I think, you need to increase the wait-time. From your stacktrace, it seems that you are using 10 seconds as wait-time. Within this short amount of time, the Logon button is not visible. Increasing waiting time may solve your problem.

Comment: :This issue is occuring only in IE11. I tried in chrome it works correctl

Answer (score 0):

@Nageswaranm, use webdriver wait and find elements using id or name or cssSelector. IE is not as good as other browsers when it comes to finding webelement using xpath. It is slow in IE . Also increase  webdriver wait to 30 second. Hope this will solve the problem.

Comment: I tried using id selector also. It also throws the same error. But same code in chrome works perfectly.